# Google Sheets App Script: Automatically sort tabs based on custom order

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, tabs

We use Google Sheets for concert production.
A TEMPLATE tab serves as template for a given concert. An ALL SHOWS tab serves as a summary.
Each time a new concert is planned, we duplicate TEMPLATE and name it according to the concert date (e.g. 01/01, 04/12), which we then move along the tab bar at the appropriate location.

In-between concert tabs are MONTHS tabs (e.g. JANUARY, FEBRUARY)

After tweaking a little with App Script, I was wondering whether anyone had a smart insight into **how I could automatically sort newly created concert tabs along the tab bar based on a custom order**.

Our custom sort order would look something like:

- HELPER (to be left in place)
- TEMPLATE (to be left in place)
- ALL CONCERTS (to be left in place)
- JANUARY
- 01/01
- 02/01
- [...]
- 31/01
- FEBRUARY
- 01/02
- 02/02
- [...]
- 28/02
- MARCH
- 01/03
- [...]
- HOLIDAYS (Occasional tab that should also be left in place)

Thank you very much for your time!

R

Comment: If I well understand, your dates are in format dd/MM

Comment: Ca you share a simple spreadsheet?

Comment: Hi @MikeSteelson! I would but my file incorporates database imports and helper files with sensitive information. I'd need to do a thourough cleaning first :)

Comment: First test my proposal, your spreadsheet could not be essential in the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sort, use moveActiSheet (see references).

The aim here is to build an array with the name of each tab and the *date* as follows

- 2022-MM-dd for tabs as xx/yy
- 2022-MM-00 for tabs as MMMM
- z for others

and sort according to the second value of each row

Try

```
function reOrderTabs() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const tabs = ss.getSheets().map(sh => sh.getName())
  const monthes = listOfMonthes()
  var list = []
  tabs.forEach(t => {
    try {
      if (monthes.indexOf(t) == -1) {
        list.push([t, '2022-' + t.split('/')[1] + '-' + t.split('/')[0]])
      }
      else {
        list.push([
          t,
          Utilities.formatDate(new Date('2022/' + (monthes.indexOf(t) + 1) + '/' + 15), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM") + '-00'
        ])
      }
    }
    catch (e) { list.push([t, 'z']) }
  })
  list = list.sort(function (a, b) {
    return ('' + a[1]).localeCompare(b[1]);
  })
  list.forEach((t, i) => { 
    ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(t[0]));
    ss.moveActiveSheet(i + 1)
  })
}

function listOfMonthes() {
  return [...Array.from(Array(12).keys(), x => Utilities.formatDate(new Date(2022, x, 15), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MMMM").toUpperCase())]
}
```

[image]

### references

[moveActiveSheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#moveactivesheetpos)

[forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

[sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

[...array](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: Re @Mike Steelon! I first went for Irvin Jay G.'s suggestion since I tested it and it worked very well. I sense though that the question I posted (i.e. how to exclude some sheets from the sorting) could be answered with your suggestion. Imma look into. Thank you very much

Comment: you can upvoted for this solution if you think it will be suefull for other people.

Comment: if you want to leave extra-tabs at the beginning, change `list.push([t, 'z'])` by `list.push([t, ' '])` with a space in place of z

Comment: This still results in first tabs being pushed to the end though. I did upvote but it tells me I need 15 reputation ;)

Answer (score 0):

## SUGGESTION

For sorting sheet tabs, the only way to do this in Apps Script is by using its [***moveActiveSheet()***](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#moveactivesheetpos) method. What I have done on my sample script below is that I gathered all the current tabs information into an array, sorted them out based on ***your custom sort order*** using a combination of [.forEach](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-foreach-how-to-loop-through-an-array-in-js/), [.map](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-map-how-to-use-the-js-map-function-array-method/), [.filter](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-array-filter-tutorial-how-to-iterate-through-elements-in-an-array/) & [.sort](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-array-sort-tutorial-how-to-use-js-sort-methods-with-code-examples/) methods & then rearranged them.

### Sample Script *[UPDATED]*

```
function main() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
  var res = [];
  var mainDates = [];

  //This will sort the sheet tabs by month name and date in ascending order ⤵
  sheet.getSheets().map((data, i) => {
    return (months.join(' ').toUpperCase().includes(data.getName())) ?
      [(parseInt(months.map((element, index) => { if (element.toUpperCase() == data.getName()) return index }).join('')) + 1), data.getName(), (i + 1)] :
      (/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(data.getName().replace(/\s+/g, ''))) ? res.unshift(['', data.getName(), '']) : mainDates.push([indetifyDate(data.getName(), months), data.getName(), (i + 1)])
  }).
    filter(x => { return x.length > 1 ? x : null }).sort(function (a, b) { return a[0] - b[0] }).
    forEach(month => {
      res.push(month);
      mainDates.sort(function (a, b) { return a[1].slice(0, 2) - b[1].slice(0, 2) }).
        forEach(data => { return data[0] == month[0] ? res.push(data.join(',').split(',')) : null })
    });
  for (var x in res) res[x][1] == "HOLIDAYS" ? res.push(res.splice(x, 1)[0]) : 0;console.log(res)
  arrangeTabs(res, sheet);
}

//This function will assign an indetifier for each tab that is in date form (e.g. 01/01) for sorting⤵
function indetifyDate(data, months) {
  var curDate = new Date(data.split('/')[1] + "/" + data.split('/')[0]).getMonth() + 1;
  return months.map((_, index) => { if ((index + 1) == curDate) return (index + 1) }).filter(x => x).join('');
}

//This function will move sheets tabs based on their order from process above ⤵
function arrangeTabs(res, sheet) {
  res.forEach((data, pos) => {
    sheet.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheetByName(data[1]))
    sheet.moveActiveSheet((pos + 1));
  })
}
```

1. Script will get all the tab names (in original positions) & places them into an array
2. Then, it will iterate through the array & filter the tabs with monthly names (e.g. JANUARY) using the first ternary condition
3. Then the next ternary condition will filter the non-date format and will [unshift](https://www.programiz.com/javascript/library/array/unshift) them to be at the beginning of the `res` array variable & the remaining tabs in `dd/mm` format will be further sorted and filtered thoroughly based on the months they belong to before being added to the `res` variable.
4. Lastly, the `HOLIDAYS` tab will be placed at the end of the `res` array variable
5. Once the `res` array has been arranged accordingly, the function `arrangeTabs` will then arrange them on the actual spreadsheet.

### Demonstration

- After running the `main` function, the tabs get sorted as seen below:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Irvin Jay G! I am truly stoked, thank you so much for taking the time this is incredible, I didn't expect such a quick answer. The script really works like charm. There's one thing left I need to tweak though. I've been trying to understand the code and play with it with no success so far. My File includes a HELPER tab as well as a SUMMARY tab, which should stay in place at the very beginning of the tab bar (i.e. not be included in the sorting). I guess my question is 'how can we specify tabs that could be left alone?'. It's my understanding that MONTHS are assigned an index.

Comment: @Richard Thanks for your comment. I have updated my script to put all non-date format tabs (such as _HELPER_,_TEMPLATE_&_ALL CONCERTS_) to be placed at the beginning & _HOLIDAYS_ tab will be placed at the end. FYI, on this implementation, these non-date tabs will still be sorted alphabetically but all three of them will be placed at the beginning of your sheet. If this answer is also helpful for you, kindly click the up-vote button to help others as well, who are seeking this kind of implementation, and they will be recommended to your post.